# How to get a calculated scalar out of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I have a `dataframe` as shown below. I want to group and return the count of `Campeão` registers, so that I can have this scalar into a output text for users.

[image]

I'm using this code to display a table with each correspondent value

`a = df['Macro RFM'].value_counts().reset_index()`

`st.dataframe(a)`

[image]

How can I get the result for each class (`Macro RFM`)? I mean, I want to output something like that:
`st.write(f'We got {X} champions')`

```
direct translation (campeão = champion)
```

Comment: Why do you count values in `Macro RFM` if you need the values from `Grupo RFM`?

Comment: Good observation @jcaliz. I made a mistake, it is `macro`. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand: you seem to have got your result already, right?  `df['Macro RFM'].value_counts()` is basically the same as `df.groupby('Macro RFM').size()`. What am I missing? To select just the `Campeão` count, do `df['Macro RFM'].value_counts().loc['Campeão']`.

Comment: @PierreD you're correct Pierre, this is want I needed, thanks! but I didn't know that, i'm new to Python, specially pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
champions = df['Macro RFM'].value_counts().loc['Campeão']
```

Or maybe filtering and using `shape` attribute:

```
champions = df[df['Macro RFM'] == 'Campeão'].shape[0]
```